# Switch to parent window after child window is closed by driver.close() throws Exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, flash-selenium

I have a scenario where I perform the following steps:

1. Open browser --> navigate to and click on link which opens a new window
2. Switch to child window using `driver.switchTo().window(handle)` --> perform operations on the child window.
3. Close the child window.
4. Switch back to the parent window.
5. Get the title of the current window.

Steps 1 to 3 works just fine. But step 4 throws an exception. And for better clarity I have included the log messages before the exception is throw.n

```
// Switching to child window
[testng] 23:40:33.794 INFO - Executing: [switch to window: 3efe9598-2a08-40ec-a950-d4a6e2182b20])
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:40:33:808 Browser.cpp(241) Unable to get window name, IHTMLWindow2::get_name failed or returned a NULL value
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:40:33:821 Browser.cpp(241) Unable to get window name, IHTMLWindow2::get_name failed or returned a NULL value
[testng] 23:40:33.942 INFO - Done: [switch to window: 3efe9598-2a08-40ec-a950-d4a6e2182b20]
[testng] 23:40:33.944 INFO - Executing: [get title])
[testng] 23:40:33.955 INFO - Done: [get title]
[testng] 23:41:34.708 INFO - Executing: [close window])
[testng] 23:41:34.719 INFO - Done: [close window]
// Switch to parent window
[testng] 23:41:34.751 INFO - Executing: [switch to window: b2dd5b6e-c891-498f-871b-1fc80b4afef2])
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:41:34:753 IECommandExecutor.cpp(595) Unable to find managed browser with id 3efe9598-2a08-40ec-a950-d4a6e2182b20
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:41:34:753 IECommandExecutor.cpp(504) Unable to find current browser
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:41:34:765 Browser.cpp(241) Unable to get window name, IHTMLWindow2::get_name failed or returned a NULL value
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:41:34:865 IECommandExecutor.cpp(595) Unable to find managed browser with id 3efe9598-2a08-40ec-a950-d4a6e2182b20
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:42:34:875 response.cc(69) Error response has status code 21 and message 'Timed out waiting for page to load.' message
[testng] 23:42:34.879 WARN - Exception thrown
[testng] org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for page to load. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
[testng] Command duration or timeout: 60.13 seconds
[testng] Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55'
[testng] System info: host: 'x-x-x-x', ip: 'x.x.x.x', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
[testng] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
[testng] Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=false, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:42778/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]`
```

We are using a special framework based on flashSelenium and our developers here have managed to integrate flash Selenium with WebDriver (Originally flash Selenium was intended to work with RC). From my understanding, our framework involves flashSelenium, RC and Webdriver components. I am new to the team and the framework API is not in active development (no support).

When I put a try catch around step 4, step 5 is executed correctly. I can see that the exception block around step 4 printing the error!!

**So here goes my question:
Does driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow) give an exception as shown above in any circumstance?**

As from the below log segment I can see that the switch to window executes but the internal method of switch window throws an Exception as the consecutive lines suggest.

```
[testng] 23:41:34.751 INFO - Executing: [switch to window: b2dd5b6e-c891-498f-871b-1fc80b4afef2])
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:41:34:753 IECommandExecutor.cpp(595) Unable to find managed browser with id 3efe9598-2a08-40ec-a950-d4a6e2182b20
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:41:34:753 IECommandExecutor.cpp(504) Unable to find current browser
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:41:34:765 Browser.cpp(241) Unable to get window name, IHTMLWindow2::get_name failed or returned a NULL value
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:41:34:865 IECommandExecutor.cpp(595) Unable to find managed browser with id 3efe9598-2a08-40ec-a950-d4a6e2182b20
[testng] W 2016-02-08 23:42:34:875 response.cc(69) Error response has status code 21 and message 'Timed out waiting for page to load.' message
[testng] 23:42:34.879 WARN - Exception thrown
```

Code looks like below

```
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
// Click on the element code goes here (This is in flash selenium)
Set<String> windowhandles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
for (String windowHandle : windowHandles) {
    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
}

System.out.println("Child title : " + driver.getTitle());
driver.close;
// Exception is thrown in the below line. If a try catch is placed
// the last line gets executed (sysout). But I can see the catch getting executed.
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
System.out.println("Child title : " + driver.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, Selenium doesn't switch automatically to parent window after using `driver.close()`. When you tried `driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow)` the driver was still focused on the closed window's window handle, that what caused the `Unable to find managed browser with id 3efe9598-2a08-40ec-a950-d4a6e2182b20` and `Unable to find current browser` messages in the error log.

If you want to switch back to parent handle you should save it before the switch

```
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(childHandle); // switch to child window
driver.close(); // close child window
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle); // switch focus back to parent window
```

Comment: Please note that IHTMLWindow2::get_name failed or returned a NULL value line was thrown when switching to the child window. When switching to the parent window another error was thrown

Comment: I have saved the parent window handle and I have used it to switchTo() parent window.

Comment: @Sighil I edited my answer to suit the switch to parent errors, but the reason is still the same.

Comment: My bad, The question was Does driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow) give an exception as shown above in any circumstance in the first place

Comment: Also, I have used the normal WebDriver code and am pretty sure that it is correct in syntax and logic. What I am confused is whether the complexity of the framework and how the WebDriver is initialized could give raise to the above conditions. I have no visibility to initialization code.

Comment: @Sighil I'm not aware of any way the initialization of the WebDriver could effect the switch back to the parent window. If there was problem there it would have rise long before then.

Comment: @Sighil Can you try something? check how many window handles you have after closing the child window and if one of them (there should be only one) has the same window handle as the parent handle `int num = driver.getWindowHandles();` `for(String s : driver.getWindowHandles()) { if (s.equals(parentHandle)) { return true; } }`

Comment: There is only one window. What if the WebDriver is initialized as a Selenium instance and the WebDriver instance is derived from it ? I have checked all the basics. Been in Selenium for 2 years. First  time I am seeing this and it is leaving me confused as hell.

Comment: @Sighil Did you change the Selenium or Browser versions lately? it sometimes causes problems.

Comment: @Sighil Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103021/discussion-between-guy-and-sighil).